# run several coroutines in parallel (with return value)

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new with kotlin I'm trying to run several requests to a web in parallel threads

so far I got

```
class HttpClient {
    private val DEFAULT_BASE_URL = "https://someapi"

    fun fetch(endPoint: String, page: Int): String {
        FuelManager.instance.basePath = DEFAULT_BASE_URL
        val (_, response, _) = endPoint.httpGet(listOf("page" to page)).response()
        return String(response.data)
    }

    fun headers(endPoint: String): Headers {
        FuelManager.instance.basePath = DEFAULT_BASE_URL
        val (_, response, _) = endPoint.httpGet(listOf("page" to 1)).response()
        return response.headers
    }
}
```

and the class that runs the whole process

```
class Fetcher(private val page: Int) {
    suspend fun run(): String = coroutineScope {
        async {
            HttpClient().fetch(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT, page)
        }
    }.await()


    companion object {

        private const val DEFAULT_ENDPOINT = "endpoint"

        suspend fun fetchAll(): MutableList<String> {

            val totalThreads = (totalCount() / pageSize()) + 1

            return runBlocking {
                var deck: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
                for (i in 1..totalThreads) {
                    deck.add(Fetcher(i).run())
                }

                deck
            }
        }

        private fun pageSize(): Int {
            return HttpClient().headers(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT)["page-size"].first().toInt()
        }

        private fun totalCount(): Int {
            return HttpClient().headers(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT)["total-count"].first().toInt()
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking to mirror the `Thread.join()` from Java. Could you give me some pointers on how to improve my code to achieve that?

Also if not much asking, could you suggest a book/example set on this subject?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few points:

1. If you're going to be using coroutines in a project, you'll mostly want to be exposing suspending functions instead of blocking functions. I don't use Fuel, but I see it [has a coroutines library](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/tree/master/fuel-coroutines) with `suspend` function versions of its blocking functions. Usually, suspend functions that unwrap an asynchronous result have the word "await" in them. I don't know for sure what `response()` is since I don't use fuel, but if I had to guess, you can use `awaitResponse()` instead and then make the functions `suspend` functions.
2. Not related to coroutines, but there's almost no reason to ever use the `String` constructor to wrap another String, since Strings are immutable. (The only reason you would ever need to copy a String in memory like that is maybe if you were using it in some kind of weird collection that uses identity comparison instead of `==`` comparison, and you need it to be treated as a different value.)
3. Also not related to coroutines, but HttpClient in your case should be a singleton `object` since it holds no state. Then you won't need to instantiate it when you use it or worry about holding a reference to one in a property.
4. **Never** use `runBlocking` in a suspend function. A suspend function must never block. `runBlocking` creates a blocking function. The only two places `runBlocking` should ever appear in an application are at the top level `main` function of a CLI app, or in an app that has both coroutines and some other thread-management library and you need to convert suspend functions into blocking non-suspend functions so they can be used by the non-coroutine-based code.
5. There's no reason to immediately follow `async()` with `await()` if you aren't doing it in parallel with something else. You could just use `withContext` instead. If you don't need to use a specific dispatcher to call the code, which you don't if it's a suspend function, then you don't even need `withContext`. You can just call suspend functions directly in your coroutine.
6. There's no reason to use `coroutineScope { }` to wrap a single child coroutine. It's for running multiple child coroutines and waiting for all of them.

So, if we change HttpClient's functions into `suspend` functions, then `Fetcher.run` becomes very simple.

I also think that it's kind of weird that `Fetcher` is a class with a single property that is only used in a one-off fashion with its only function. Instead, it would be more straight-forward for Fetcher to be a singleton object and for `run` to have the parameter it needs. Then you won't need a companion object either since Fetcher as an object can directly host those functions.

Finally, the part you were actually asking about: to run parallel tasks in a coroutine, use `coroutineScope { }` and then launch `async` coroutines inside it and await them. The `map` function is handy for doing this with something you can iterate, and then you can use `awaitAll()`. You can also get `totalCount` and `pageSize` in parallel.

Bringing that all together:

```
object HttpClient {
    private val DEFAULT_BASE_URL = "https://someapi"

    suspend fun fetch(endPoint: String, page: Int): String {
        FuelManager.instance.basePath = DEFAULT_BASE_URL
        val (_, response, _) = endPoint.httpGet(listOf("page" to page)).awaitResponse()
        return response.data
    }

    suspend fun headers(endPoint: String): Headers {
        FuelManager.instance.basePath = DEFAULT_BASE_URL
        val (_, response, _) = endPoint.httpGet(listOf("page" to 1)).awaitResponse()
        return response.headers
    }
}
```

```
object Fetcher() {
    suspend fun run(page: Int): String = 
        HttpClient.fetch(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT, page)

    private const val DEFAULT_ENDPOINT = "endpoint"

    suspend fun fetchAll(): List<String> {
        val totalThreads = coroutineScope {
            val totalCount = async { totalCount() }
            val pageSize = async { pageSize() }
            (totalCount.await() / pageSize.await()) + 1
        }
        return coroutineScope {
            (1..totalThreads).map { i ->
                async { run(i) }
            }.awaitAll()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun pageSize(): Int {
        return HttpClient.headers(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT)["page-size"].first().toInt()
    }

    private suspend fun totalCount(): Int {
        return HttpClient.headers(DEFAULT_ENDPOINT)["total-count"].first().toInt()
    }

}
```

I changed MutableList to List, since it's simpler, and usually you don't need a MutableList. If you really need one you can call `toMutableList()` on it.

Comment: Awesome. I appreciate the code review besides the question asked . A follow up question: I get `Redundant 'suspend' modifier` suggestion on the IDE on the run method

Comment: Another question: if totalThreads is a large number(let's say 1000), would it be opening 1000 threads?  is there a way to control the thread pool?
Thanks again!

Comment: If it says "redundant suspend modifier", it means it isn't calling any other suspend functions, which means you didn't change the `fetch` function like in my code above. The number of actual threads created would be determined by the thread-pool used by Fuel in this case. With many APIs, the underlying thread pool would be some kind of Java Executor(s). In Fuel's case, looking at it very briefly [here](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/blob/master/fuel-coroutines/src/main/kotlin/com/github/kittinunf/fuel/coroutines/Coroutines.kt), it seems that the extension functions are simply using ...

Comment: ...the Kotlin coroutines library to call blocking Fuel functions using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`. This means it is pulling threads from Kotlin coroutines' Dispatchers.IO's pool, which typically has up to 64 threads. More details [here](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html). In Kotlin coroutines, Dispatchers are essentially thread pools.